# Keras LSTM Conversion to Core ML Results in Differently Shaped Input Layer

Tags: keras, lstm, coreml, coremltools

I have converted a [Keras model](https://github.com/bfelbo/DeepMoji/blob/master/deepmoji/model_def.py) into a Core ML model using `coremltools`. The original Keras model has the following architecture:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
word_embeddings (InputLayer)    (None, 30)           0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding (Embedding)           (None, 30, 256)      12800000    input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
activation_1 (Activation)       (None, 30, 256)      0           embedding[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bi_lstm_0 (Bidirectional)       (None, 30, 1024)     3149824     activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bi_lstm_1 (Bidirectional)       (None, 30, 1024)     6295552     bi_lstm_0[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_1 (Concatenate)     (None, 30, 2304)     0           bi_lstm_1[0][0]                  
                                                                 bi_lstm_0[0][0]                  
                                                                 activation_1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
attlayer (AttentionWeightedAver (None, 2304)         2304        concatenate_1[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
softmax (Dense)                 (None, 64)           147520      attlayer[0][0]                   
==================================================================================================
```

I can run inferences against the model in Keras/Python with the following input:

```py
model.predict(tokenized)

# where tokenized = [[  13   93  276  356   11 2469   18  144  453  269   11    0    0    0
#     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#     0    0]]
# of class 'numpy.ndarray' and shape (1, 30)
```

However, after conversion, my Core ML model shows the following shape for the input layer.

```
input {
  name: "word_embeddings"
  type {
    multiArrayType {
      shape: 1
      dataType: FLOAT32
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

**Why has the input layer (`word_embeddings`) lost its shape after Core ML conversion? I would expect its type to show `MultiArray (Float32 1 x 30)`. Ideally, I would like to be able to pass in a full 30-element vector as I did previously.**

I've read [Apple's Core ML LSTM doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/core_ml_api/making_predictions_with_a_sequence_of_inputs) which suggests that I may need to repeatedly call `model.prediction(..)` with a single element at a time, capturing the output states of each prediction and passing them in as input to the next until I've reached the end of the full sequence (all 30 elements). Alternatively, could I leverage the [Core ML Batch API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mlmodel/2962866-predictions) to make this easier?

Is this necessary?

*For context, the model takes a "sentence", that is, a list of 30 words (tokenized to unique integers) and outputs an "emoji" classification, one of 64 possible values.*

Conversion running in Colab with coremltools == 3.3 with keras == 2.3.1 and Python 2.7.17.

Comment: please add code of the model consruction , python version and keras version